# Incorrect syntax near ',' in php for query

Tags: php, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error

I am not a PHP developer , but i have got work to complete.

The error i am facing is

> Warning:  mssql_query() [ function.mssql-query]: message:
>   Incorrect syntax near ','. (severity 15) in
>   **\webapis\db_functions.php** on line **343**

Line 343 is

```
  $result = mssql_query($SQL)
```

where my php code is

```
public function BookOrder( $OrderNo , $OrderDate , $OrderRetailerId  , $OrderDistributorId  , $OrderAgentId , $OrderTotalItems , $OrderTotalBaseAmt , $OrderTaxTotal , $OrderTotal ,$OrderRemark , $OrderCreatedById , $OrderCreatedOrigin , $OrderDeactivate ){

    $timestamp = strtotime($OrderDate);
    $date_formated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);

     $SQL = "INSERT INTO BookOrder( OrderNo , OrderDate , OrderRetailerId , OrderDistributorId , OrderAgentId , OrderTotalItems , OrderTotalBaseAmt , OrderTaxTotal , OrderTotal , OrderRemark , OrderSMSStat , OrderCreatedById , OrderCreatedOrigin , OrderDeactivate , CmpId ) VALUES ( ".$OrderNo." , '".$timestamp."' , ".$OrderRetailerId." , ".$OrderDistributorId." , ".$OrderAgentId.", ".$OrderTotalItems." , ".$OrderTotalBaseAmt." , ".$OrderTaxTotal." , ".$OrderTotal.", '".$OrderRemark."', 0 , ".$OrderCreatedById." , '".$OrderCreatedOrigin."' , ".$OrderDeactivate." , 0 )";

    $result = mssql_query($SQL)
     or die("An error occured:");

     if ($result) { 

     $query1 = "select SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS last_insert_id";

     $queryResult1 = mssql_query($query1)
           or die("Query Failed");

     $queryResult1 = mssql_fetch_object($queryResult1);

    $id = $queryResult1->last_insert_id;

        $arr['status'] = "true";
        $arr['id'] = $id;
        mssql_close($this->conn);
        return $arr ;

    } else { 

        $arr['status'] = "false";
        $arr['id'] = 0;
        mssql_close($this->conn);
        return $arr ;
    }

}
```

I have checked the parameters i am sending to the calling function , they are correct. I have googled a lot but no luck.

Database columns are as follows:

```
[dbo].[BookOrder](
[OrderId] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderNo] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
[OrderRetailerId] [int] NULL,
[OrderDistributorId] [int] NULL,
[OrderAgentId] [int] NULL,
[OrderTotalItems] [float] NULL,
[OrderTotalBaseAmt] [float] NULL,
[OrderTaxTotal] [float] NULL,
[OrderTotal] [float] NULL,
[OrderRemark] [varchar](150) NULL,
[OrderSMSStat] [bit] NULL,
[OrderCreatedById] [int] NULL,
[OrderCreatedOrigin] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OrderDeactivate] [bit] NULL,
[CmpId] [int] NULL,
```

Can anyone guide me here solving this issue.?

Comment: Can you run SQL profiler to check the exact SQL query executed against the database?

Comment: Your values in your sql query aren't quoted which results in a SQL error. Consider using the PDO library. The `mssql_*` functions are deprecated and removed as of PHP 7

Comment: @BhatiaAshish: i am damn new to PHP and never ever used SQL Server software. any link can you provide me to run sql Profiler. i am using SQL Server mgt studio..

Comment: @Cfreak :Hi . My database has 14 tables , where i am already inserting data successfully , i cant change all the code now or migrate to any other lib. shall i change the table structure or any other solution.

Comment: @Cfreak : is it `mysql` or `mssql` ?

Comment: @Cfreak : mssql

Comment: Java enthusiastic: you can just Google for `mysqli + php`

Comment: Yes it is `mssql`.  See here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

The lib is a suggestion. If you print out your query you'll see your values are not quoted.

Comment: @C2486 he's using MS SQL Server. `mysqli` will not help.

Comment: @C2486 :   $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

this is my code.. is it mysqli or shall i go ahead with your suggestion.?

Comment: i changed the connection line to 
$this->conn = mssql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)

still the same error i am getting.

Comment: Add `echo $SQL` before `$result = mssql_query($SQL)`, and check this query from SSMS.

Comment: @Leran2002 : Cool. Tested , found that some values were going null. repaired them and query is getting hit. but another issue has occurred now , mssql_query(): 4 is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in
, here also i followed echo $SQL and pasted it in SMSS , it is getting inserted but here in php it is not.?
any suggestion.

Comment: @JavaEnthusias - You do `mssql_close` but I don't see where do you do `mssql_connect`. Maybe you need to open connection before your query. If it isn't problem then check the connection ID `$conn_id = mssql_connect(...); echo $conn_id;`.

Comment: @Leran2002 : hi , i have written the code in another file db_connect.php where i am successfully creating the connection and its object.

Comment: @JavaEnthusias - I think `conn` is a property of the class that contains the method `BookOrder`. How do you set a value into this property? - `$c = new YourClass(); $c->conn=mssql_connect(...);` or `$this->conn = new mysqli(...); $c = new YourClass(); $c->conn = $this->conn;`? As variant you want to use `conn` from another class and don't set `conn` of this class.

Comment: @Leran2002 :     $this->conn = mssql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)
                     or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server");

Comment: and in functions class i get the db object like this 

$db = new db_connect();
  $this->conn = $db->connect();

Comment: @JavaEnthusias - Try to do `$result = mssql_query($SQL, $this->conn)...`. If it doesn't work then check `echo $this->conn;` before it. It's difficult to help without all the necessary source code.

Comment: @Leran2002 : Let me try this,, if it wont work i will share the source code.